# Inequality for nonegative real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, holder-inequality

Let $0\leq a,b\leq 1$ and $1<p<\infty$, then prove the following inequality:
$$
|a^p-b^p|\leq p(a^p+b^p)^\frac{p-1}{p}|a-b|.
$$
Thanks in advance.

I tried to prove in the following way and hope this is correct: Kindly inform me.

Let $f(x)=x^p$, $x\in[0,1]$. Then by the MVT, we know for some $t\in(0,1)$
$$
f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(a+tb)=(b-a)p(a+tb)^{p-1}\leq p|a-b|(a+tb)^{p-1}\leq p|a-b|(a+b)^{p-1}\leq p2^{p-1}|a-b|(a^p+b^p)^\frac{p-1}{p},
$$
where the last inequality above holds due to the fact that
$$
(a+b)^{p}\leq 2^{p}(a^p+b^p).
$$

But I want to constant to be $p$ in place of $p2^{p-1}$ on the right-hand side. Can somebody please help me with the same? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please say what you have tried and where you got stuck. Cheers

Comment: Are you sure this inequality is true ?

Comment: @Bachamohamed, The inequality is certainly true, I've proved it, but I can't write my answer on a question which doesn't follow guidelines.

Comment: Hi, I have updated what I tried and found. Kindly have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to finish with your approach but I give you my proof just using some simple calculations.

Let $x=\frac{a}{b}$ and assume that $x\geq 1$. The inequality is equivalent to

$$x^p-1 \leq p(x^p+1)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}(x-1)$$

Define $f(x)=p(x^p+1)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}(x-1)-x^p+1$ and note that $f(1)=0$.

If my computation is right, then we have

\begin{align}
f'(x)&=p(x^p+1)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}+p(p-1)(x-1)(x^p+1)^{-\frac{1}{p}}-px^{p-1}\\
&\geq p(x^p+1)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}-px^{p-1}\\
&>0.
\end{align}
So $f(x)$ is increasing, then $f(x)\geq f(1)=0$.